# How to redirect in laravel using prefix?

Tags: php, laravel, redirect

I want to redirect a user in situation whenever he typed for example:

> `https://coolbrand/X/blah/bla`  to => `https://coolbrand/Y/blah/bla`,

So finally i want to change the only one element in URL address(in this case `X => Y`) rest must stay the without any changes.

I would like to use prefix

Comment: And where do you plan to do this ? Javascript or a controller ? If it is on the backend, you can use `middlewares`, or directly do it on the controller pointing to that route... Show us your code and we will help you.

Comment: which version of laravel?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know in which Laravel version you are working on,
As far I have understang your question you can try the following

> **Note:** this is for Laravel Version: 8.x

**Routes**

```
Route::get('/coolbrand/{type}/blah/bla', 'App\Http\Controllers\YourController@callYourFunction')->name('blabal-route');
```

**You can call route in blade file like following with parameters**

```
{{ route('blabal-route', ['type'=>'X']) }} // in case of X
{{ route('blabal-route', ['type'=>'Y']) }} // in case of Y
```

**In Controller**

```
public function callYourFunction(Request $request){
    $type = $request->type // either it is X or Y
    // further execution
}
```

Hope it will work for you.